# Using marquee TextView in RecyclerView will stop scroll after refresh

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm using marquee `TextView` in `RecyclerView`. To activate scrolling(marquee) I have to call `textView.isSelected = true` inside `onBindViewHolder()`.

This marquee is working but as I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in some of my items this scroll effect is deactivated. If I scroll up and down again to redraw items it is working fine again.

How to fix this issue?

```
adapter = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemVH>(){
            override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemVH{
                val layout = CustomResources.inflateLayout(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                    R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false)
                return ItemVH(layout)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(vh: ItemVH, i: Int) {
                        val item = itemList[i]
                        with(vh){
                            textView.apply {
                                if (!isSelected) isSelected = true
                            }
                            ...
                        }
             }
```

Also tried to set same parameters again in code what I have in XML but without change.

```
textView.apply {
    marqueeRepeatLimit = -1
    setHorizontallyScrolling(true)
    setSingleLine()
    ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
    if (!isSelected) isSelected = true
}
```

`notifyItemChanged()` is causing the same issue.

Comment: Can you post your adapter code please ?

Comment: Code above was my first attempt to fix this. That I will only select it if it is not selected but without change. Before I have there only textView.isSelected = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed this. This is weird bug in Android, but if you change text color of that TextView with marquee after you set isSelected to true, it will stop marquee effect.

```
textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, getColorFromAttr(R.attr.textColorPrimary)))
```

I have to call `textView.isSelected = true` after this code for some reason.